# Custom remarkable markdown plugin only parsing first instance of matched regex

Tags: regex, reactjs, plugins, markdown

I am trying to create a plugin using [remarkable](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable) which will convert

```
%[callout]
{
    "type": "info",
    "heading": "LOL",
    "description": "qwrqwer!"
}
[/callout]
```

to a `div` showing the parsed json. Here is my code on [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9q3rr65v6o).

As you can see on the sandbox that it is showing a smiley emoji correctly if you paste the above code block in the `textarea`. But if you paste the same code multiple times it is only showing the emoji for only first instance of that code block and directly rendering the code block as a text for all subsequent occurences.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems the pro'blem is in callouts.js. The solutuion is rather banal: remove `g` modifier. Use `const reg = /%\[callout\]\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*\[\/callout]/i;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it worked. Don't how I missed that.